# Why $\tan^{-2}(x) = \frac{1}{\tan^2(x)}$?

Tags: trigonometry

If tan^-1(x) can't be 1/tanx then why can tan^-2(x) =1/tanx
Actually I know than tan^-1(x) is the inverse trigonometry and it is equal to tan($\theta)$ so why don't tan^-2(x) is equal to tan^2($\theta)$.

Comment: It’s literally a problem of bad notation. There is a clash between the notation for inverse function, $f^{-1}(y)$ (as the function that “undoes” what $f$ does) and the notation used for powers of trigonometric functions, where we write $\tan^2(x)$ instead of $(\tan(x))^2$. This clash means the symbol $\tan^{-1}(x)$ is **ambiguous**: it could mean either the reciprocal or the inverse function. By convention, it means the **inverse**, and by convention, $n=-1$ is the **only** value of $n$ for which $\tan^n(x)$ does *not* mean $(\tan(x))^n$. So for $n=-2$, it *does* mean that. (cont)

Comment: As Hendrik Lenstra used to say, “Unfortunately, I cannot help this bad notation: I did not create this part of the world.”

Comment: Your post would be more readable if you used [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Arturo Magidin said in the comments, it is a matter of notation. Usually, $\sin^n(x),\cos^n(x),\tan^n(x)$ denote $(\sin(x))^n,(\cos(x))^n,(\tan(x))^n$ respectively, when $n=1,2,\dots$. Unfortunately, due to various historical reasons, when $n=-1$, the notation $\sin^{-1}(x),\cos^{-1}(x),\tan^{-1}(x)$ do not at all mean $1$ divided by the respective functions, but rather represent the inverse function.

Your confusion probably comes from your teacher/textbook using $\tan^{-2}(x)$ to mean $(\tan(x))^{-2}$ instead of $(\tan^{-1}(x))^2$ or $\tan^{-1}(\tan^{-1}(x))$. This confusing notation unfortunately rather common. The good news is that there's nothing conceptual you're missing, it's just an instance of particularly confusing notation.

Comment: For the record, I give a 5 minute speech on this when I teach calculus, and I stick to the notation $\arctan$ instead of the book's $\tan^{-1}$...

Comment: @Arturo Magidin .. that's the type of teacher we(students) need in the classes.